# Can't mount or edit VHDX file, in use

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, hyper-v, network-attached-storage, vhdx

OS is Windows Server 2012

I have a VHDX file that we've been using for backups since Windows won't play nice with our NAS. The first 6 backups worked flawlessly, and they show up in the Windows server backup control panel.

However, subsequent backups have failed with the error: "disk not available." Sure enough, I can't mount the VHD anymore, with the error, "permission denied." The permissions on the file are set fine, I should have full control, and so should the backup operators.

So I thought maybe the VHD is full and it's giving me an error because of that. But when I try to resize the VHD, it says the file is in use by another process. I used process explorer to check for open file handles and saw that SYSTEM (PID 4) had two handles on the file. I then rebooted and tried again, same issue. I also stopped the hyper v service and tried, to no avail. Windows complains that the file is open in another process, although this time, process explorer shows no open file handles to the VHD.

I'm a bit stumped here. What could be going on? Anyone else use a VHD for backup or have another revomendation for backing up over a NAS? We're using Windows server backup and doing a full server backup. About 6TB of data.

Thanks!

Comment: Comment: you're using the worst possible way to backup 6TB of data, VHDs are not meant to be used as a backup solution, I'd seriously rethink my backup strategy if I were you. Suggestion) can you take the disk hosting the VHD to another machine and test opening it? I have a theory that the disk is corrupted but is giving you a different error. if that's not possible then try to start your server in SafeMode and mount the VHD again.

Comment: I understand it's not ideal, but the backups wouldn't run at all by just specifying the NAS share. If you have suggestions for running backups to a NAS, I'd happily hear them.